# Matrix Relations

Tags: matrices

We have the relation $\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x_{n}\\y_{n}\end{bmatrix}$. How do you explain why $\begin{bmatrix}x_n\\y_n\end{bmatrix}$=$A^n\begin{bmatrix}x_{0}\\y_{0}\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2):

For the proposition in the question to be true, we require the relation in the question to hold for all nonnegative integers less than or equal to some positive integer $N.\ $ Suppose this is the case. Then for any positive integer $n\leq N,$ we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_n\\y_n\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-1}\\y_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = A \left( A\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-2}\\y_{n-2}\end{bmatrix} \right) \overset{\text{(1)}}{=} (A A)\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-2}\\y_{n-2}\end{bmatrix} \overset{\text{(2)}}{=} A^2\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-2}\\y_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ = A^2 \left( A \begin{bmatrix}x_{n-3}\\y_{n-3}\end{bmatrix} \right) = A^3\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-3}\\y_{n-3}\end{bmatrix} = \ldots = A^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{bmatrix} =  A^n\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$$$
$(1)$ holds because matrix multiplication is associative.

$(2)$ holds because the definition of $A^2$ is $AA.$

Comment: Perhaps I answered too hastily, as this is a low-quality question. Oh well.